# pattern file as an input to RS,FS in awk/sed/grep to recognize and add columns

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed, grep, python

I have a file which has the patterns that I have to find in the given data set and add the numbers in a columns of the data. I want to write a script or use awk/sed/grep to automatically query the patterns in a given file to cross check with the data I have and to add the numbers in the columns with matching pattern.

**Example:-**

**Data**

**TITLE,COUNT,RESA**

```
10th ECOMF,PAB  1   MAT

10th ICOCPS (CPV-'10)   23  SCI

10th ICOCPS (CPV-'10)   6   SCI

10th ICOMAMOS (M2S-X)   3   EEE

JOP 32  COP

AIP 34  Sff

JOP 43  COP

HIT 42  tilde
```

**My pattern file consists names of the journals:-**

```
10th ECOMF,PAB

10th ICOCPS (CPV-'10)

10th ICOCPS (CPV-'10)

10th ICOMAMOS (M2S-X)

JOP

AIP

JOP

HIT

SUPERCONDUCTIVITY (M2S-X)
```

**Desired output:**

```
10th ECOMF,PAB  1

10th ICOCPS (CPV-'10)   29

10th ICOMAMOS (M2S-X)   3

JOP 75

AIP 34

HIT 42

.

.
```

so on,

PS:- Data is Tab-separated, I same data in CSV too.

Comment: Is your pattern file tab separated? 10th ICOCPS (CPV-'10) is this one column??

Comment: @user3138373 Yes, it is one column. File is in tab-separated values.


:: Kamaraj, Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="\t" }
     NR==FNR{ if(NF && !($0 in b)) { a[++c]=$0; b[$0] } next }{ b[$1]+=$2 }
     END{ len=length(a); for(i=1;i<=len;i++) if(a[i] in b) print a[i],b[a[i]] }' patterns data
```

---

- `BEGIN{ FS=OFS="\t" }` - setting field separator
- `a[++c]=$0; b[$0]` - collecting unique *journal* names from `patterns` file
- `b[$1]+=$2` - summing up the numbers for each *journal* name within `data` file
- `if(a[i] in b) print a[i],b[a[i]]` - append sum value to each *journal* name in the `pattern` file

The output:

```
10th ECOMF,PAB  1
10th ICOCPS (CPV-'10)   29
10th ICOMAMOS (M2S-X)   3
JOP 75
AIP 34
HIT 42
...
```

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly. I upvoted the answer, but it says -"vote cast by those with less than 15 reputations are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed score "

Comment: @CCC, you have my upvote to your question